# Disable/de-activate a custom component with published property

Tags: delphi, constructor, delphi-7, custom-component

i am working on a custom component in `Delphi -7` for which i have some `published` properties

```
   private
     { Private declarations }
     FFolderzip  ,Fimagezip,Ftextzip,FActivatezipComp   : Boolean;
     FMessagebo : string;
   published
    { Published declarations }
    {component Properties}
    {#1.Folder Zip}
    property ZipFolder : Boolean read FFolderzip  write FFolderzip  default False;
    {#2.Send imagezip ?}
    property ZipImage : Boolean read Fimagezip   write Fimagezip   default False;
    {#3.text files}
    property ZipText : Boolean read Ftextzip   write Ftextzip   default False;
    {#4.message}
    property ZipMessage: String read FMessagebo write FMessagebo ; 
    {#5.Activate }
    property ActivateZipper: Boolean read FActivatezipComp write  FActivatezipComp Default false;
   end;
```

When the user drops the component on the application, `ActivateZipper` properties give the use a option to activate/enable or deactivate/disable the component from executing.
The component creates a file
so in the constructor i have this, `CreateATextFileProc` will create the file in the application folder.So if i check in the constructor if the `ActivateZipper` is true or false..

i have a `constructor`

```
     constructor TcomProj.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
     begin
       inherited;
       if ActivateZipper then CreateATextFileProc;
     end;
```

The `ActivateZipper` is always false even if i set it to true in the object inspector.
How can the component be disabled from doing it working with published property?

Comment: `ActivateZipper` is always False in the constructor because objects are zero initialised. It will be set True when the properties are streamed in. Are you aware that most apps run without sufficient rights to write to the application folder?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ok, and for sufficient rights i guess the manifest file for higher privileges can be used ..since the component is internal now we can take care hopefully of that

Comment: @PresleyDias, I've seen few of your questions related to this same component and I think you don't quite understand Delphi component philosophy. Therefore, I wholeheartedly recommend that you read [Delphi Component Design by Danny Thorpe](http://www.amazon.com/Delphi-Component-Design-Danny-Thorpe/dp/0201461366). Although this book is very old, most of its contents still apply to this subject.

Comment: @LightBulb yes, im a new to this component creation,modification and customization. ..thank you for the link..wholeheartedly appreciated

Comment: I'm with @LightBulb. What you are doing here sounds all wrong. And as for manifesting admin rights, that's a bad idea. Simply write the file to a location to which you have rights. Avoid requiring admin rights like you avoid the plague.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `C:\Documents and Settings\Myname\Application Data\myfolder` (i guess this is better) thank you:)

Comment: PresleyDias: [This post] might be helpful to you; it shows various ways to get the proper folders regardless of Windows version.

Comment: @KenWhite i think u missed the link:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor is too early.  The design-time property values have not been streamed into the component yet.  You need to wait until your component's `Loaded()` method is called before you can then act on the values.  If you create the component dynamically at run-time, you also need a property setter since there are no DFM values and thus `Loaded()` will not be called.

```
type
  TcomProj = class(TComponent)
  private 
    ...
    procedure SetActivateZipper(Value: Boolean);
  protected
    procedure Loaded; override;
  published 
    property ActivateZipper: Boolean read FActivatezipComp write SetActivateZipper; 
  end; 

procedure TcomProj.SetActivateZipper(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FActivatezipComp <> Value then
  begin
    FActivatezipComp := Value;
    if ActivateZipper and ((ComponentState * [csDesigning, csLoading, csLoading]) = []) then
      CreateATextFileProc; 
  end;
end;

procedure TcomProj.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  if ActivateZipper then CreateATextFileProc; 
end;
```

Comment: +1 But just for some extra clarification: Loaded is only needed when `CreateATextFileProc` depends on other properties that may not have been set/loaded yet; the property setter is called anyway. Should have mentioned it though!

Comment: Yes, the property setter is always called, which is why I coded it to check the `ComponentState` property so `CreateATextFileProc()` does not get called at design-time or during DFM streaming.

Comment: [+1,accepted] it works..!!...please remove the extra brace `)` from if ActivateZipper and ((ComponentState * [csDesigning, csLoading, csLoading `)` ]) = []) then..i cannot remove as the edit is too small

Answer (score 2):

> `ActivateZipper` is always False even if I set it to True in the object inspector.

Your activation code is now placed in the constructor. A few things about that:

- In the constructor, all private fields are zero (0, '', null, nil, depending on type) initialized. If you do not set it otherwise, then these fields remain zero once the component is created.
- When you are changing properties with the object inspector, the component is already created.
- Your code will never run.
- When you do want to initialize it otherwise at creation, then change also the default storage specifier.

What you need is a *property setter* that will be invoked whenever the property is changed by means of object inspector or code:

```
  private
    procedure SetZipperActive(Value: Boolean);
  published
    property ZipperActive: Boolean read FZipperActive write SetZipperActive default False;

procedure TcomProj.SetZipperActive(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FZipperActive <> Value then
  begin
    FZipperActive := Value;
    if FZipperActive then
      CreateATextFile
    else
      ...
end;
```

You might consider to turn off this functionality at design-time, since it is likely that you want the actual zipping only at run-time. Then test for the `csDesigning` flag in [`ComponentState`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponentState):

```
procedure TcomProj.SetZipperActive(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FZipperActive <> Value then
  begin
    FZipperActive := Value;
    if csDesigning in ComponentState then
      if FZipperActive then
        CreateATextFile
      else
        ...
end;
```

Comment: +1,Thank you but how it will be called during creation?..better idea would be to set `ZipperActive:=true` ?in the application code?

Comment: Then add `ZipperActive := True` (or `SetZipperActive(True)` which is nearly the same) in the constructor.

Comment: The constructor is simply the wrong place to be managing the text file at all.  You have to wait until `Loaded()` has been called first, except in the case when the component is constructed in code instead of at design-time. See my answer for an example of how to handle both situations.